# How to add structured data schema in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I add structured data mainEntity as an array @type question?

As you can see from my code, I need to have the main entity as an array so I can pass advanced custom fields repeater rows into the schema in an attempt to build an [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ).

The fields that I'm trying to pass into the structured data is a very basic ACF repeater as you can see here:

```
<section class="faq">
    <div class="container max-width px-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 features-title-block">
                <h2 class="mpc-header"> <?php if ( get_field('faq_header') ) : ?>
                    <?php the_field('faq_header'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?></h2>
                    <?php if ( get_field('faq_sub_text') ) : ?>
                    <div class="pb-5"><?php the_field('faq_sub_text'); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php if ( have_rows('faq') ) : ?>
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <?php while( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link d-inline-flex" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" aria-expanded="true"
                                    aria-controls="collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_sub_field('question'); ?>
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" class="collapse"
                            aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php
                    $schema = array(
                    '@context'   => "https://schema.org",
                    '@type'      => "FAQPage",
                    'mainEntity' => array()
                    );
                    global $schema;
                    if ( have_rows('faq') ) {
                        while ( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row();
                            $questions = array(
                                '@type'          => 'Question',
                                'name'           => get_sub_field('question'),
                                'acceptedAnswer' => array(
                                '@type' => "Answer",
                                'text' => get_sub_field('answer')
                                )
                                );
                                array_push($schema['mainEntity'], $questions);
                                        endwhile;
                    function generate_faq_schema ($schema) {
                    global $schema;
                    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">'. json_encode($schema) .'</script>';
                    }
                    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'generate_faq_schema', 100 );
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- endif have_rows('faq'); -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi @BradHolmes, can you please paste array which is required and array in the current form ? It will be easy to understand your requirement

Comment: Hi @AabirHussain i have update the question with the acf repeater information

Comment: Are you getting any error or warning  ? According to my understanding, you are able to display FAQ but unable to generate Schema right ?

Comment: One more thing why you need global $schema; you can move condition & loop inside the `generate_faq_schema` instead of calculating outside the function. I thing the issue belong here. If you thing I am going into right direction, I can paste an answer for this code.

Comment: yes faq displays fine its just the schema that is the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<section class="faq">
    <div class="container max-width px-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 features-title-block">
                <h2 class="mpc-header"> <?php if ( get_field('faq_header') ) : ?>
                    <?php the_field('faq_header'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?></h2>
                    <?php if ( get_field('faq_sub_text') ) : ?>
                    <div class="pb-5"><?php the_field('faq_sub_text'); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php if ( have_rows('faq') ) : ?>
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <?php while( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link d-inline-flex" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" aria-expanded="true"
                                    aria-controls="collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>">

                                    <?php the_sub_field('question'); ?>

                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" class="collapse"
                            aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="faq-content card-body">
                                <?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php
                    $schema = array(
                    '@context'   => "https://schema.org",
                    '@type'      => "FAQPage",
                    'mainEntity' => array()
                    );
                    global $schema;
                    if ( have_rows('faq') ) {
                        while ( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row();
                            $questions = array(
                                '@type'          => 'Question',
                                'name'           => get_sub_field('question'),
                                'acceptedAnswer' => array(
                                '@type' => "Answer",
                                'text' => get_sub_field('answer')
                                )
                                );
                                array_push($schema['mainEntity'], $questions);
                                        endwhile;
                    function generate_faq_schema ($schema) {
                    global $schema;
                    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">'. json_encode($schema) .'</script>';
                    }
                    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'generate_faq_schema', 100 );
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- endif have_rows('faq'); -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

After lots of testing, both answers received some sort of a result, but the actually working code has no errors and is pulling through to Google is above.

Please feel free to make any suggestion on making this better.

Comment: can you explain why you need global $schema; It will be helpful for me for the future thanks

Answer (score 6):

I am not a pro in WordPress, but if you avoid global variables as much as you can, this will be good for your application. Just try the below code.

```
<?php
function generate_faq_schema () {
    if ( have_rows('faq') ) {
        $schema = [
            '@context'   => "https://schema.org",
            '@type'      => "FAQPage",
            'mainEntity' => array()
        ];
        while ( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row();
            $questions = [
                '@type'          => 'Question',
                'name'           => get_sub_field('question'),
                'acceptedAnswer' => [
                    '@type' => "Answer",
                    'text' => get_sub_field('answer')
                ]
            ];
            array_push($schema['mainEntity'], $questions);
        endwhile;
        echo '<script type="application/ld+json">'. json_encode($schema) .'</script>';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'generate_faq_schema', 100 );

?>
```

Also check for fourth argument of **add_action** [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested to output the exact format you are looking for, and here are the snippets of mine as an example:

```
<?php
    global $schema;

    $schema = array(
        '@context' => "https://schema.org",
        '@type' => "FAQPage",
        'mainEntity' => array()
    );

    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('template-parts/post-formats/post', get_post_format());
        array_push($schema['mainEntity'], array(
            '@type' => get_post_format(),
            'title' => get_the_title()
        ));
    }

    function generate_faq_schema()
    {
        global $schema;
        echo '<script type="application/ld+json">' . json_encode($schema) . '</script>';
    }

    add_action('wp_footer', 'generate_faq_schema', 100);
?>
```